# A detail in I. Piatetski-Shapiro and S. Rallis's "Doubling paper": computing the integral on negligible orbits

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

I'm currently reading the paper ["L-functions for the classical groups"](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0078126) by I. Piatetski-Shapiro and S. Rallis, where they introduced the doubling method over classical groups.

I'm confused at the calculation of the **negligible orbits** on page 5. There we wrote the inner integral of $I(\gamma)$ as
$$
\mathcal{I} = \int_{M_k \backslash M_{\mathbb{A}}} \int_{N_k \backslash N_{\mathbb{A}}^\gamma} f(\gamma(n_1, n_2)(m_1, m_2)(g_1^{\prime}, g_2^{\prime})) \phi_1(n_1 m_1 g_1^{\prime}) \phi_2(n_2 m_2 g_2^{\prime}) \,\mathrm{d}n_1 \mathrm{d}n_2 \mathrm{d}m_1 \mathrm{d}m_2.
$$
Then to see that this integral vanishes, the authors separate $N^{\gamma} = N_1 \times N_2$ and shift the inner integral to $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$. They claimed
$$
\mathcal{I} = \int_{M_k \backslash M_{\mathbb{A}}} f(\gamma(m_1, m_2)(g_1^{\prime}, g_2^{\prime})) \left( \int_{N_{1,k} \backslash N_{1,\mathbb{A}}}\phi_1(n_1 m_1 g_1^{\prime}) \,\mathrm{d}n_1 \right) \left( \int_{N_{2,k} \backslash N_{2,\mathbb{A}}} \phi_2(n_2 m_2 g_2^{\prime})  \mathrm{d}n_2 \right)\mathrm{d}m_1 \mathrm{d}m_2.
$$

Comparing the above two lines, **I'm really confused on** how the element $(n_1, n_2)$ disappeared in the section $f \in \mathrm{Ind}_{P(\mathbb{A})}^{G(\mathbb{A})}(\omega \circ \delta_P)$.

**My attempts**: Recall $(n_1, n_2) \in N^{\gamma} \unlhd (G \times G)^\gamma$, where the latter is the stabilizer of $\gamma \in X:= P \backslash H$ under the action of $G \times G$, we can find $p \in P$ such that $\gamma (n_1, n_2) = p \gamma$.

**Stuck point 1**: But this particular $p \in P$ depends on $(n_1, n_2) \in H$. So why can we move the integral $\int_N$ to the right skipping $f(\cdots)$?

**Stuck point 2**: Even we rewrite
$$
f(\gamma(n_1, n_2)(m_1, m_2)(g_1^{\prime}, g_2^{\prime})) = f(p\gamma(m_1, m_2)(g_1^{\prime}, g_2^{\prime})) = \omega(\delta(p)) f(\gamma(m_1, m_2)(g_1^{\prime}, g_2^{\prime})),
$$
then how can I know that $\delta(p)=1$? In the paper, it seems that the authors were suggesting that $p$ is actually in $N$, hence the modulus character $\delta$ takes $p$ to $1$. But I cannot see why this holds.

This is where I got stucked. Sorry for maybe not providing enough background as it seems that this is quite a famous paper. Thanks all for paying attention, commenting and answering!